# How to properly replace Gradle 'jar' task?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to force Gradle to create jar my own way. I wrote my own Gradle task (separate class) to do this and now I want to replace the default `jar` task with it, so that:

- the archive is ALWAYS generated with my new task and NEVER with the old `jar` task
- my new task has the same relationship with other tasks as the default `jar` task - it depends on `classes` task, the `build` task uses it, etc.
- I would like my task not to be invoked when it's `UP-TO-DATE` (just like the default `jar`)

I'm struggling to do this and I'm having a lot of trouble to achieve this. For example, I was unable to force the `build` task to always use my new task.

I would really appreciate it if someone could support me with a short howto.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
jar {
    // reset actions
    actions = []
    // add your action that performs the work based
    // on the configuration (e.g. 'source') of this task
    doLast { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Old `jar` is never executed anymore. However, the task is executed always, even if it should be `UP-TO-DATE`. How can I prevent that?

Comment: If you run with `--info`, Gradle will tell you why it thinks that the task is not up-to-date.